# pandas - Resample a dataframe using a specified start date, end date and granularity

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample a datetime indexed dataframe using a start date, an end date and a 'granularity'

Say I have this dataframe:

```
                   value
00:00, 01/05/2017    2
12:00, 01/05/2017    4
00:00, 02/05/2017    6
12:00, 02/05/2017    8
00:00, 03/05/2017   10
12:00, 03/05/2017   12
```

And I want to resample it to go from `06:00, 01/05/2017` to
`18:00 02/05/2017` with a 'granularity' of 12 hours (this is the same as the original here for simplicity but doesn't have to be). The result I want is:

```
                   value
06:00, 01/05/2017    3
18:00, 01/05/2017    5
06:00, 02/05/2017    7
18:00, 02/05/2017    9
```

Note that the values are the mean of the values they overlap (e.g. 3 = mean(2,4))

I'm unsure how to do this.

My first attempt was:

```
def resample(df: DataFrame, start: datetime, end: datetime, granularity: timedelta) -> DataFrame:
    result = df.resample(granularity).mean()
    result = result[result.index <= end]
    result = result[result.index >= start]
    return result
```

This trims the data frame appropriately and ensures the correct granularity but doesn't align the results with the start date so the result is:

```
                   value
12:00, 01/05/2017    4
00:00, 02/05/2017    6
12:00, 02/05/2017    8
```

My second attempt used the `base` parameter to shift the data:

```
def resample(df: DataFrame, start: datetime, end: datetime, desired_granularity: timedelta) -> DataFrame:
    data_before_start = df[df.index <= start]
    # Get the last index value before our start date
    last_date_before_start = data_before_start.last_valid_index()
    current_granularity_secs = seconds_between_measurements(df)
    rule = str(int(desired_granularity.total_seconds())) + 'S'
    base = current_granularity_secs - (start - last_date_before_start).total_seconds()
    result = df.resample(rule, base=base).mean()
    result = result[result.index < end]
    result = result[result.index >= start]
    return result
```

This gives me:

```
                   value
06:00, 01/05/2017    4
18:00, 01/05/2017    6
06:00, 02/05/2017    8
18:00, 02/05/2017    10
```

This has the right indices but the values are backfilled from the next measurement rather than averaged from the measurements before and after.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance for your help and just let me know if I've left out any crucial details :)

**EDIT:**
If getting the mean is the bit that makes this very tricky, I could settle for using the value before the given time, similar to pad(). My current 'best' solution gives me the value after, like backfill()

Answer (score 1):

First define your end_start and end_date columns as datetime.
Then, you can use `.resample` two times:

- On df.start_date with a forward filling
- On df.end_date with a backward filling

Then:

- Keep row where start_date < end_date
- Concatenate
- Apply on each row a function to update start_date and end_date:

Here the code:

```
df[["start_date","end_date"]] = df[["start_date","end_date"]].astype(np.datetime64)
df1 = df.set_index("start_date").resample(freq).pad().reset_index()
df2 = df.set_index("end_date").resample(freq).bfill().reset_index()
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

def function(x, df1):
    if x.name < df1.shape[0]:
        x.end_date = x.start_date + pd.Timedelta(freq)
    else:
        x.start_date = x.end_date - pd.Timedelta(freq)
    return x

df3[ df3.start_date < df3.end_date ].apply(lambda x: function(x, df1), axis=1)
```

> Pandas documentation say that it should be possible directly to resample
>
> `df.resample(freq, on='start_date')`